# Java:How to override this generic method?

Tags: java, generics, overriding, type-erasure

```
public <S extends T> List<S> save(Iterable<S> entities) {
        //...
}
```

If I use following method to override

```
@Override
public List<MyType> save(Iterable<MyType> structures) {
    List<MyType> result = new ArrayList<>();
    //...
    return result;
}
```

I get following error:

```
method does not override or implement a method from a supertype

name clash: save(Iterable<MyType>) in MyTypeRepositoryImpl and <S>save(Iterable<S>) in SimpleJpaRepository have the same erasure, yet neither overrides the other
  where S,T are type-variables:
    S extends T declared in method <S>save(Iterable<S>)
    T extends Object declared in class SimpleJpaRepository
```

How can I solve this? I don't need the method to be generic and in fact it should not be. What I mean is that

```
@Override
public <S extends MyType> List<S> save(Iterable<S> structures) {
    List<S> result = new ArrayList<>();
    //...
    return result;
}
```

Will not work as the method can create a new Object of MyType which is not "compatible" to List.

How can I make this work?

EDIT:

For clarification. I'm trying to override the different save() methods of Spring data SimpleJpaRepository (which is extented by QuerydslJpaRepository)

Class defintions:

```
public class MyTypeRepositoryImpl
    extends QueryDslJpaRepository<MyType, Long>
    implements MyTypeRepository

@NoRepositoryBean
public interface MyTypeRepository
    extends JpaRepository<MyType, Long>,
    QueryDslPredicateExecutor<MyType>
```

And this (from Spring Data)

```
public class QueryDslJpaRepository<T, ID extends Serializable> 
extends SimpleJpaRepository<T, ID> 
implements QueryDslPredicateExecutor<T>
```

EDIT 2:

The method calls save(MyType entity) for each element and that method contains following logic:

1. entity has a field which is unique
2. get that fields value and check if entity with that value already exists
3. if yes, use that entity (call to entityManager.merge) -> does not work returns MyType not S
4. if no create a new one -> here new object is created. Does not work with generic type

For 4. I can just set id = null and use the passed in object. That does not work for 3.

So I'm very puzzled why this method has this signature. It makes it unusable for me and i don't get why I would save a subclass of T using Ts DAO. the save methods are the only ones with . All others just use T. I could just cast to S to make it compile but that seems ugly too...as any other type than T would lead to an exception.

Comment: How are the containing classes declared?

Comment: what do you mean by not "compatible" to List?  It looks like from the original `<S extends T>` parameter that the class is made to be able to be used by doing something like `implements InterfaceName<MyType>` without having to muck around with subclassing

Comment: From the comments to other answers and the fact that you are extending a class over which you have no control, I believe you are forced to use `public <S extends MyType> List<S> save(Iterable<S> structures)`. This is because the overridden method is genericized and so the overridding method must also be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to not override this at all but to create a service class that does the needed logic and leave repository untouched.

Comment: No offence, but this is not a solution to your problem you have stated in the question, hence not the "best" answer either. what you've ended up doing is a work around

Answer (score 13):

For one method to override another it must apply to at least all valid parameters of the overridden method. Your base method is generic `public <S extends T> List<S> save(Iterable<S> entities)`. So it will accept any type `S` that extends `T`. However your override is more restrictive because it will only accept collections of `MyType`, therefore it is not a valid override.

If you had your base class defined with `T`, and the method accepted just `T`, and the derived class locked down `T` to `MyType` you should be OK.

To give a better answer we need to see the class declarations for the two classes. I would suggest the following:

```
class MyClass<T>{
  public List<T> save(Iterable<T> entities);
}

class OtherClass extends MyClass<MyType>{
  public List<MyType> save(Iterable<MyType> entities);
}
```

EDIT:

If you don't have control over the base class (which it seems that you don't), you are stuck with the `public <S extends MyType> List<S> save(Iterable<S> structures)` signature. This is because the overridden method is genericized and so the overridding method must also be

Answer (score 3):

Depends on how you have defined , the following works

```
public class TestGenerics2<T> {
    public <S extends T> List<S> save(Iterable<S> entities) {
        return new ArrayList<S>();
    }
}

public class TestGenerics3 extends TestGenerics2<Number> {
    @Override
    public <S extends Number> List<S> save(Iterable<S> entities) {
        return super.save(entities);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example that compiles and that shows how to use it:

```
abstract class A<T> {
    abstract public <S extends T> List<S> save(Iterable<S> entities); 
}

class B extends A<List<Integer>> {

    @Override
    public <S extends List<Integer>> List<S> save(Iterable<S> entities) {
        return null;
    }
}

class C {
    public void useIt() {
        B b = new B();
        Iterable<ArrayList<Integer>> it = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
        b.save(it);
    }
}
```

Class `A` defines the method with the original signature. class `B` implements it and chooses `List<Integer>` for type parameter `T`. And finally, class `C` uses this method with an `Iterable` whore generic type is a subclass of `List<Integer>`.

Comment: I get that. But I do not need the <S extends T>. T is a fixed Type, eg. always the same type, and T is a final class. Besides that depending on input I'm creating a new Object of MyType in the method. Mytype newObject = new MyType(args); That does not work with S.

Comment: Confused. If a final class is used for `T` then you won't find a class for `S` which makes the method quite unusable (for this case)

Comment: Doesn't T fulfill S? I'm confused now too. :O

Comment: Sorry. I was wrong. I wanted the class to be final but it is an Entity and the can't be final.

Answer (score 1):

Since

```
public <S extends T> List<S> save(Iterable<S> entities)
```

is given, your override must be for

```
public <S extends MyType> List<S> save(Iterable<S> structures)
```

and your implementation must respect that S might be a real subtype of MyType.

Your approach

```
public List<MyType> save(Iterable<MyType> structures)
```

is not a correct override:

- since Java >=1.5 allows [covariant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_%28computer_science%29#Java) return types and `List<MyType>` is a subtype of `List<S extends MyType>`, this is ok, but
- Java only allows invariant parameter types, but `Iterable<MyType>` is a subtype of `Iterable<S extends MyType>`, hence your compiler error message.

Comment: I'm not declaring the method I override. It's an existing class from Spring Data. See edit.

Comment: IC, adopted my answer accordingly.