# Why does declaring Java Generic Type at Class vs Method level pass compilation

Tags: java, generics, compilation

> Note: This question may seem similar to
> [Java generic method inheritance and override rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5346847/java-generic-method-inheritance-and-override-rules),
> but I'm interested in why declaring the type parameter at the class
> level causes the compilation to pass.

In the following code, StringMaker2 successfully compiles when it implements `Maker2<String>` However, StringMaker1 fails compilation when it implements Maker1 with:

```
GenericsTest.java: name clash: make(java.lang.Class<java.lang.String>) in GenericsTest.StringMaker1 and 
<T>make(java.lang.Class<T>) in GenericsTest.Maker1 have the same erasure, yet neither overrides the other
```

The only different between Maker1 and Maker2 is that that the type parameter, `<T>`, is defined at the method level in the former and class level in the later.

Could someone explain why this makes a difference?

```
public class GenericsTest {

    interface Maker1 {
        <T> T make(Class<T> type) throws Exception;
    }
    
    interface Maker2<T> {
        T make(Class<T> type) throws Exception;
    }
    
    // This class fails compilation
    class StringMaker1 implements Maker1 {

        @Override
        public String make(Class<String> type) throws Exception {
            return type.newInstance();
        }
    }
    
    class StringMaker2 implements Maker2<String> {

        @Override
        public String make(Class<String> type) throws Exception {
            return type.newInstance();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The answer is in the error message: `public String make` does not override `<T> T make`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't override methods like that.  Interface `Maker1` declares a generic method; you can't change that without changing the method signature (which causes a compile error).  Interface `Maker2` the *interface* is generic, not the method.  Parameterizing the interface is OK so the method compiles.

Comment: You can't limit scope of acceptable method arguments while overriding it. Remember that subtypes can be assigned to variables of supertype like `Maker1 m1 = new StringMaker1();`. Since `m1` is of type `Maker1` it should allow user to call its `<T> T make(Class<T> type)` method so it includes `Class<Integer>` and any other class literals, not just `Class<String>`.

Comment: In your `Maker1` interface, the type variable `<T>` _is a parameter to the method_, and you can't change that signature when implementing.

Comment: Thank you to @markspace. The link to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13049420/javahow-to-override-this-generic-method helped. As did @Pshemo explanation.

I now understand how the StringMaker1 override incorrect restricts the signature of Maker1. In Maker2, the Type may be restricted by the implementing class but this keeps the signature valid.

Because `Maker2<String> m = new StringMaker2()` passes compilation as the parameterized type agrees with the type of the `m` reference.